# WRT54G router with tomato firmware doesn't connect to internet if Windows 8 PC is suspended

Tags: windows-8, lan, dhcp, tomato, suspend

This problem began occurring within the past couple of days, and to my knowledge I made no changes to any hardware or to my network layout.

I have a Windows 8 PC connected to a gigabit switch (D-Link DGS-2205) on the LAN side of a WRT54G router running Tomato Firmware v1.25.1720, and two laptops connected to the router by wifi, one Windows 8, and one XP.  The router's WAN port is connected to a switch (SMCFS8) which is in turn connected to my ADSL modem.  My TV is ADSL and is also connected to the modem via the switch.

```
ADSL Modem -> SMCFS8
               |-> WRT54G -> DGS-2205 -> Win8 PC, Win7 PC
               |     |
               |     |-(wifi)-> XP Laptop, Win8 Laptop
               |
               |-> ADSL TV Box
```

**The problem is**: After suspending my Windows 8 PC at night, in the morning the WRT54G has lost internet connectivity (LAN still works).

- Power cycling the router doesn't help
- Power cycling the modem doesn't help
- Waking or rebooting either of the laptops connected to wifi doesn't help (they can connect to the router via wifi, but the router has no internet connectivity)
- The TV works during this time

**What does work**: is waking the Windows 8 PC from sleep, which immediately resolves whatever issue the router was having, allowing it to obtain a DHCP lease, and internet connectivity is restored for all of the computers. **Update:** Unplugging the sleeping windows 8 machine's LAN cable also restores connectivity. This makes me think there is possibly something electrical going on? Or WOL related?

If I just suspend my PC at a random time while I'm at home, internet connectivity may be lost almost immediately or much later.

**What is going on?**

I will continue looking into the issue and post a resolution if I find one.

- Is UPnP somehow messing with the router's ability to connect, and the Windows 8 PC is either notifying or resetting the router in some way that allows it to re-connect.
- **Update:** UPnP is now disabled under the Port Forwarding area of Tomato's interface, this doesn't appear to have made a difference.
- The only hardware related change I made recently was plugging my printer into my Windows 8 PC through USB for the first time since I upgraded to Win8
- The only software change I made was installing a game on the Windows 8 PC that I uninstalled the next day
- No network topology changes had happened for a week or two prior to the issue beginning

*At this point I'm more interested in knowing the root cause out of curiosity than actually resolving the issue, although that would be a nice benefit.*

Comment: Is there a reason why you're running 1.25 and not the latest version, 1.28? Is this a mod of Tomato or the stock release? Why the switch in front of the router and is the WAN port set to be part of the LAN bridge?

Comment: I haven't upgraded the tomato firmware because I've never had reason to, it has worked fine for years. The switch is in front of the router as both my router and tv-box box need to be connected to the adsl modem.

Comment: almost sounds like an ip or mac address conflict. maybe a rogue device is duplicating one or the other. might also try disabling ipv6 in the win8 box and see if that provides a clue.

Comment: I would update tomato -> disable WOL if on -> install ubuntu within windows and test suspend -> install another network card.